# i have IndexError: Invalid key: 447 is out of bounds for size 0

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I was trying to train a model that adds captions to images and I don't know why it sends me an error in "trainer.train()" that "IndexError: Invalid key: 447 is out of bounds for size 0"

```
from datasets import load_dataset,DatasetDict
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

ds = load_dataset("lambdalabs/pokemon-blip-captions", split = "train")
# Split the dataset into train and remaining sets
train_val_ds, test_ds = train_test_split(ds, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Convert DatasetDict to Dataset
train_ds, val_ds = train_test_split(
    ds, test_size=0.4, shuffle=True, random_state=42
)

# Convert the Dataset to DatasetDict
train_ds = DatasetDict({"image": train_ds["image"], "text": train_ds["text"]})
val_ds = DatasetDict({"image": val_ds["image"], "text": val_ds["text"]})

# Convert DatasetDict to Dataset
train = datasets.Dataset.from_dict(train_ds)
val = datasets.Dataset.from_dict(val_ds)

# and the rest of the code 


# the block that contain the error
import torch
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding,AutoTokenizer

trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=train,
    eval_dataset=val,
    data_collator=DataCollatorWithPadding(processor, return_tensors="pt"),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=processor,
)

trainer.train()
trainer.save_model("./model")
```

thank you for helping in advance
please help me♡

I tried to print the train and validation dataset to make sure that they contains info

```
print(f"Train dataset length: {len(train_ds)}")
print(f"Validation dataset length: {len(val_ds)}")
```

**the output:**
Train dataset length: 499
Validation dataset length: 334

and even for the original :

```
print(f"Original dataset length: {len(ds)}")
print("Original dataset features:")
print(ds.features)
```

**the output:**
Original dataset length: 833
Original dataset features:
{'image': Image(decode=True, id=None), 'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}